# Backbone - Array of Models to JSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I know there's plenty of ways to do this... but why isn't this approach working?

```
var selected = this.collection.where({checked: true});

var mapped = _.map(selected, Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call);

this.$el.html(this.template(mapped));
```

Error is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Is there a more succinct way?

**EDIT** This did what I wanted...

```
var mapped = _.invoke(selected, Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON);
```

**EDIT 2** @nikoshr made it better.

```
var mapped = _.invoke(selected, 'toJSON');
```

Comment: need to state the question clearly.  whats not working about it?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: where is the `TypeError` happening? it should have a line number - which of the three lines triggers it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in [`_.map`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-16) source code, you will see, as of version 1.5.1

```
_.map = _.collect = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    var results = [];
    if (obj == null) return results;
    if (nativeMap && obj.map === nativeMap) return obj.map(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      results.push(iterator.call(context, value, index, list));
    });
    return results;
};
```

which means that for each object in `selected`, you will end with `Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call.call` and an unspecified context, which probably isn't what you want.

The simplest way to call `toJSON` on each model would be to use [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke):

> **invoke** _.invoke(list, methodName, [*arguments])
>   Calls the method named
>   by methodName on each value in the list.

Applied to your case :

```
var mapped = _.invoke(selected, 'toJSON');
```

And a demo

```js
var c = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id: 1, checked: true},
    {id: 2, checked: false},
    {id: 3, checked: true}
]);
var selected = c.where({checked: true});

var mapped = _.invoke(selected, 'toJSON');
console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if mapped is what you expect it is, use breakpoints in the chrome debugger or add console.log(mapped). If mapped looks OK then you're probably not passing some value to the template.
If you have further problems post the  definitions of the model, collection and the template.
And BTW is this.template a function, again  see with the debugger or console.log(typeof this.template)

Comment: Good point about `this.template` - one common idiom in Backbone is `_.template(this.template({....}))` where `this.template` is actually some markup.

Comment: Instead of underscore templates, I use www.socketstream.org which supplies precompiled jade templates so my rendering code looks like ss.tmpl['template-name'].render({data}) , I guess it's different for handlebars or some other option.